# SwiftUI switch between NavigationViewStyles

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I want to present a nested list of lists either as a tree or as a grid. While the tree looks good in the split view on iPad, the grid is too big to fit.

Thus I would like to present this view using the `StackNavigationViewStyle` when in the grid display mode and using the `DefaultNavigationViewStyle`  when in the tree display mode.

I have a toggle `showList` to store the mode and I want to use at as follows to switch to navigation view style:

```
.navigationViewStyle(self.showList ? DefaultNavigationViewStyle() : StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

But the compiler complains that:

> Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types
> 'DefaultNavigationViewStyle' and 'StackNavigationViewStyle'

even though both inherit from `NavigationViewStyle`.

Is it even possible to switch between navigation view styles or is it that once I pick one I have to stick to it in that view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use ternary operator in `navigationViewStyle` modifier, because styles have different types, but you can use custom modifier like the following

```
extension NavigationView {
    @ViewBuilder
    func switchStyle(if flag: Bool) -> some View {
        if flag {
            self.navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle())
        } else {
            self.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        }
    }
}
```